# Fingerprint Scanner Animation in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I created a fingerprint scanner animation in CSS, but I encountered an issue where the scanner animation does not stay in place and instead follows the animation of the scanning board. For more details, I have attached the my codesandbox link below.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-tess-g39kdx)

I would really appreciate your help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-position: center` uses the element height to calculate the central position for the background image. You are animating the element's height so the central position is constantly changing. You will need to set a fixed location for `background-position`.

Setting the background image to be 75px from the top seems to be the right position.

```css
.scan .retina::before {
    /* other css */
    background-position: 0 75px;
}
```

Comment: i've tried your solution, and it works well. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The top image moves with the scan because it is created using a CSS animation that animates the height of the image from 0% to 100% and back to 0% over a duration of 4 seconds. This animation is applied to the pseudo-element `::before` of the `.scan .retina` element using the animate keyframe rule.

The `::before` pseudo-element is positioned absolutely with respect to the `.scan .retina` element, and its height is animated to fill the entire height of the `.scan .retina` element.

Since the `::before` pseudo-element is layered above the background image of the `.scan .retina` element, the appearance of the background image appears to move along with the animation.